# Three js memory leak

Tags: javascript, c++, memory, memory-leaks, three.js

I have recently started working on JS and threejs to develop a car game kind of environment.

The setup : The data to be displayed every frame is coming from local server to websocket and passed to three js for rendering. Since the data(objects like cars) are being continuously received in the socket and then displayed on three js, I just do "scene.remove(mesh)" for all the objects every frame and hope the GC clears the memory for it.

The issue: There is a major memory leak happening in some part of the code, which I am not able to understand. 
Attached is the screenshot for the memory usage using chrome dev tools.[memory leak screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFsnG.png) .The occupied memory in my browser goes upto about 2 Gb. I am trying to figure out if the leak is caused due to DOM to browser references or just the three js objects(mesh, geometries) not being disposed ? These are the two reasons I could understand after reading memory leaks extensively but still could not fix my problem.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does C++ come into the picture? (Pun intended :))

Comment: There's no some special place in three.js where memory could be leaked. Look for it in your code. Closures, stored in event listeners could give you a hint.

Comment: Check this example : http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_test_memory

Comment: you are probably creating the geometry upon receiving it ant this can be thousands and tens of thousands of javascript objects. No bueno. You should post some code...